# Обратное действие связи Many to One в hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Имеется две сущности, User и UserProperty. UserProperty имеет 2 поля: user, и property. Говоря обычным языком, несколько свойств могут быть применены к какому-либо пользователю. Хотелось бы получить список свойств каждого user наиболее элегантным способом.

Код Main.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class Main {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        void init() {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        User userA = new User("A");
        User userB = new User("B");
        UserProperty userPropertyA1 = new UserProperty(userA, "strong");
        UserProperty userPropertyA2 = new UserProperty(userA, "brave");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(userA);
        session.save(userB);
        session.save(userPropertyA1);
        session.save(userPropertyA2);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    void showProperties() {
        init();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<UserProperty> properties = session.createQuery("from UserProperty").list();
        for (UserProperty up: properties) {
            System.out.printf("User %s is %s\n", up.user.name, up.property);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().showProperties();
    }
}
```

Код User.java:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    User() {}
    User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // Hibernate умеет работать без геттеров и сеттеров, 
    // поэтому мы их опускаем
}
```

Код UserProperty.java:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;

@Entity
public class UserProperty {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    public User user;
    public String property;

    UserProperty() {}
    UserProperty(User user, String property) {
        this.user = user;
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Код hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider
        </property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.mycompany.hibtest.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.mycompany.hibtest.UserProperty"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Код pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.145</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Что мы используем:

```
    for (UserProperty up: userProperties) {
        System.out.printf("User %s is %s\n", up.user.name, up.property);
    }
```

Что хотелось бы использовать:

```
    for (UserExtension ue: extendedUserList) {
        for (UserProperty up: ue.properties) {
            System.out.printf("User %s is %s\n", ue.name, up.property);
        }
    }
```

Можно самому реализовать логику, которая в процессе исполнения создает список этих расширенных пользователей, и наполняет его имеющимися данными, но это не интересно.  Мой вопрос в том, можно ли реализовать эту логику средствами hibernate (без изменения структуры бд)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вам нужно использовать аннотацию `@OneToMany` в классе пользователя
Например

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<UserProperty> userProperties;
```

Comment: Хорошая мысль, чуть позже расскажу что получилось.